# Dispatching from one webapp2.RequestHandler to another

Tags: python, webapp2

Is there a way to internally pass on the handling of a request from one `RequestHandler` subclass to another? Basically, what I would like to do is, from the `get` method of a `RequestHandler` (well, a subclass of `RequestHandler`), dispatch the task of handling the request to another handler (subclass of `RequestHandler`), whose name is determined by a value fetched from the datastore (I'm using GAE, but that is irrelevant to this problem). The code would look something like this:

```
class Dispatcher(RequestHandler):
    def get_handler(some_id):
        handler_name = get_handler_name(some_id) # fetches from datastore/etc.
        return getattr(my_module, handler_name)

    def get(self, some_id, *args, **kwargs):
        handler = get_handler(some_id) # e.g., handler could be a HandlerA

        # Not a real function, just to describe what to do:
        # invokes get method of HandlerA (if handler == HandlerA)
        dispatch_to_handler(handler, self, *args, **kwargs) 

    def post(self, some_id):
        handler = get_handler(some_id)

        dispatch_to_handler(....) # dispatches to post method of the handler


class HandlerA(RequestHandler):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        do_stuff()

    def post(...):
        do_post_stuff()
```

The big issue is that I need to somehow pass `self` and the positional and keyword arguments on to the other handler (HandlerA in this example), as `self` contains the request, response, session, authentication, and other data, which `HandlerA` (or whatever the handler may be) needs in order to process the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
def get(self, some_id, *args, **kwargs)
    handler_cls = get_handler(some_id)
    handler = handler_cls(self.request, self.response)
    return handler.dispatch()
```