# How to get handler class based on the URL in a handler itself?

Tags: python, webapp2

I thought a long time how to even ask this question. Forgive me if the title is not clear enough.

So I have single page application where all the routing is done in JavaScript (AngularJS). From the server I return only partial HTMLs as needed. Now I'd like to make sure Google can index my application using _escaped_fragment_. For example in my application I have an URL:

http://example.com/user/profile/a

This would become:

http://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=user/profile/a

When Google is indexing me. That means that all requests would go through my IndexHandler that has to decide what to do with it.

Inside IndexHandler I'd like to somehow get the class that handless '/user/profile/a' so I can call special method on it that returns full HTML for a page (not partial).

Pseudo code would look something liek this:

```
 class IndexHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

        # In my example this would return 'user/profile/a'
        fragment = self.request.GET.get('_escaped_fragment_', '')

        if fragment:
            fragment = '/' + fragment

            # This is something I have no idea how to do
            clas_Im_looking_for = XXXX(fragment).get_handler()

            response = webapp2.Response()
            handler = clas_Im_looking_for(request, response)

            # Fragment get is my method
            response = handler.fragment_get()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788806/dispatching-from-one-webapp2-requesthandler-to-another

Answer (score 0):

I am not a SEO expert but I would suggest to redirect the incomming requests to "friendly URLs" using 301 redirects. In this way you make sure the nice URLs are indexed, and so any ony finding you're site will also use there URLs to hit you're app.

You should make sure these URLs respond in  away that makes sense to the users ...

This also solves you problem of assigning the correct handler to handle the URLs. Yous app knows how to do that. As you are now in a specific handler of the app, you are in fact a level to deep to know about the routing.

There may be a way to back reference the top level app object using `self.app` in handler code or use something like `webapp2.get_app()` to get hold of the app object, and than use the router to get match the correct handler (documented [here](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.Router))

However the redirect solution is for more elegant:

```
class IndexHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

        # In my example this would return 'user/profile/a'
        fragment = self.request.GET.get('_escaped_fragment_', '')

        if fragment:
            fragment = '/' + fragment
            self.redirect(fragment, permanent=True)
```